# How to adjust size of `facet_wrap` multiple stack plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have `csv` files that each has multiple stack plot, but input csv files named with rather long character. However, in my resulted plot, full name of csv files not fully printed in `facet_wrap` which easily confused category of plot are referring to. I am trying to adjust the size of `face_wrap` by using `space`, `scale` parameter, but full name of input csv files still is not displayed. Can anyone point me how to deal with csv files with rather long pattern that must be displayed in resulted plot ? How can I make this happen ? Any idea ?

I have csv file which named with rather long character (just toy example here) :

```
TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText.csv
```

This is my resulted plot and desired plot that I want to achieve (here I showed multiple stack plot for only one `csv` file) :

[image]

I intend to continue the code part of my original plot. How can I get my desired plot ? Any way to tune size of `face_wrap` where rather long named file can be displayed in resulted plot ? Thanks a lot :)

**Edit** :

I want to adjust the space between multiple stack plot for each `csv` file as well. If multiple plot of two or three `csv` files are placed in one single page, How to dynamically adjust space, and plot size that make sure rather long named `csv` files are more readable. How can I achieve this ? Any idea please ?

**New Edit** :

```
Qualified <- list(
    hotankarmaykuchakorla = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=20), end=seq(4, by=6, len=20), pos.score=sample(30, 20)),
    aksukexkerawataltay = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=15), end=seq(6, by=9, len=15), pos.score=sample(28, 15))
)

UnQualified <- list(
    hotankarmaykuchakorla = data.frame( begin=seq(9, by=12, len=30), end=seq(14, by=12, len=30), pos.score=sample(35, 30)),
    aksukexkerawataltay = data.frame( begin=seq(13, by=10, len=20), end=seq(19, by=10, len=20), pos.score=sample(34, 20))
)
```

get multiple stack plot for this:

```
hotankarmaykuchakorla.validCandidate.Qualified.csv
hotankarmaykuchakorla.validCandidate.unQualified.csv
hotankarmaykuchakorla.invalidCandidate.Qualified.csv
hotankarmaykuchakorla.invalidCandidate.UnQualified.csv
```

Comment: Maybe introduce `/n` newline in the name, instead of stretching the plot to fit the title?

Comment: See how the title is being wrapped here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Titles_(ggplot2)/

Comment: In case you're writing plots to file, you can increase the "width" parameter when creating the device. In order to manage unknown file-names, count characters and insert "\n" accordingly (or increase width)

Comment: The easiest way to do this is by using the `label` argument in facet wrap and using the built in function `label_wrap_gen()`.  http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/labeller.html

Comment: You have 8 dfs in `DF` list, how do you want 4 plots?

Comment: `var` should be space separated, change `.` dot to space, then use label_wrap_gen.

Comment: Please add ggplot code to get that plot

Comment: `facet_wrap(~var, label = label_wrap_gen(10), scales = "free_x")`

Comment: These are the tools that you can use, while they can help the length of the name is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using newline:

```
library(ggplot2)

# dummy data
df1 <- mtcars[, 1:3]
# make new long name
df1$cyl <- paste0("TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText", df1$cyl, ".csv")
# add newline
df1$cylWrap <- 
  paste0(substr(df1$cyl, 1, 20), "\n",
         substr(df1$cyl, 21, nchar(df1$cyl)))

# plot
ggplot(df1, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap( ~cylWrap, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

Comment: @Dan you can use this custom function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27734975/680068

Comment: your answer is helpful, it helped me to solve my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @Dan it is encouraged to [post an answer to your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), please share.