# How to cut a long text character in a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a long text that I want to plot to an image in R, the image size 300 x 200 pixel. The actual text will vary.

**Example Image**

[image]

**Example Code**

```
library(raster) 
myJPG <- stack("images/1.jpg")  # Image with 300 x 200 pixel size
plotRGB(myJPG)  

vt <- rep(1:100)
vt <- paste(vt, collapse = ' ')


text(x = 150, y = 70,
     labels = vt,
     adj = c(0.5,0.5),
     cex = 1,
     col = "white")
```

**Example Result.**

[image: result]

What I want to ask How to cut the text in **labels** automatically, and adjust it so all the text can be shown in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `\n` into your character vector `vt` to break a line. One way to do this automatically [is with `strwrap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174479/14992857).

```
library(raster) 
myJPG <- stack("~/Documents/1.jpg")  # Image with 300 x 200 pixel size
plotRGB(myJPG)  

vt <- rep(1:100)
vt <- paste(vt, collapse = ' ')
vt2 <- paste(strwrap(
  x = vt,
  width = 70),
collapse = "\n")

text(x = 150, y = 70,
     labels = vt2,
     adj = c(0.5,0.5),
     cex = 1,
     col = "white")
```

[image]

Comment: Another option could be to use textbox from ggtext, which will reflow automatically within a text box whose coordinates you can specify.  https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/plotting_text.html